# Generics without a specific type

Tags: c#, generics

I have this:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var result = new Result<int, bool> { success = true, Data = 88 };
            var result2 = new Result<string, bool> { success = true, Data = "Niels" };


            Console.WriteLine(result2.success);
            Console.WriteLine(result2.Data);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public class Result<T, TU>
    {
        public TU success { get; set; }
        public T Data { get; set; }


    }
```

So this is a simple generic class with two properties.

I was just wondering, how to make this:

```
var result = new Result<int, bool> { success = true, Data = 88 };
```

even more generic :). Because you still have to "say" what the return type will be: `<int, bool>`

So is it possible to do it for example like this:

```
<T var1, T var2> ?
```

Thank you

So I mean like this:

```
var result = new Result<T var1, T var2> { success = true, Data = 88 };
```

So that you can fill in for success and for Data whatever you want(string, int , float, bool)..

Comment: You mean you want to create an instance of `Result` without explicitely writing the generic types?

Comment: `public Result<T, TU> f(T t, TU tu) => new Result<T, TU>(t, tu);` is more generic. But the compiler has to get the type parameters from somewhere. You'll have to be more specific about what `<T var1, T var2>` is meant to signify.

Comment: Constructors can´t infer the generic type-arguments automatically. However methods *can*, so use a factory-method as provided by grek40.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a factory method to resolve the types automatically from the given parameters:

```
public static class ResultFactory
{
    public static Result<T, TU> Create<T, TU>(TU success, T data)
    {
        return new Result<T, TU> { success = success, Data = data };
    }
}

var result = ResultFactory.Create(true, 88);
var result2 = ResultFactory.Create(true, "Niels");
```

Comment: Thank you. But where is the Create comming from?

Comment: @Default thanks, may I never again write code in the answer window instead of an actual IDE

Comment: @LikeToDo It's the method name in the `Factory` class

Comment: @grek40 lol, it's a haphazard. It may help to use an online compiler, for instance https://dotnetfiddle.net/. It has helped me many times.

Comment: ? And where is the factory class then?

Comment: And what do you mean with this:  "in the answer window instead of an actual IDE"

Comment: @LikeToDo The `ResultFactory` class is in the answer. And the *answer window* was targeted at user *Default*, because I made a silly mistake in my code, which happened because I didn't test it properly.

Comment: Yes, oke, Because I also just added the method body to the return new.. but first I didnt understand that. but oke. can happen. Thank you

Comment: @Ahmed. I don't see your post. Can you show it? will be nice

Answer (score 0):

> Because you still have to "say" what the return type will be: `<int, bool>`

Yes you will have to specify the type `T,TU` and can't keep the type open. Types must be closed at compile time. Thus calling it like `<T var1, T var2>` won't be possible unless it's wrapped inside another generic type or method